# Cosmos SDK experiences timeouts if mapped ports in docker-compose file differ

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb

This question was originally asked by **ben-graffle** on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/50).
I'm posting here to widen the audience for this question.

Receiving 408 timeouts with the cosmos C# SDK with specific port mapping configurations in a docker-compose file

docker compose that works

```
cosmos:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
    container_name: cosmos
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 10251:10251
      - 10252:10252
      - 10253:10253
      - 10254:10254
    expose:
      - "8081"
      - "10251-10255"
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=6
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=false
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=${LOCALIPADDRESS}
```

docker compose that does not work

```
cosmos:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
    container_name: cosmos
    expose:
      - "8081"
      - "10251-10255"
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
      - 10252:10251
      - 10253:10252
      - 10254:10253
      - 10255:10254
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=6
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=false
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=${LOCALIPADDRESS}
```

Function call that throws exception

```
var httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
};

CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    HttpClientFactory = () => new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler),
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
    Serializer = new CosmosJsonNetCustomSerializer(),
    RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)
};

using CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmosEndpoint, COMSOS_KEY, cosmosClientOptions);

var db = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("GraffleMinerDatabase", 4000, null, CancellationToken.None);
```

The first docker-compose yaml works and the second does not. Receiving the following error

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: RequestTimeout (408); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 2f24681b-db18-44aa-afc8-e12ba02d8930; Reason: (GatewayStoreClient Request Timeout. Start Time UTC:03/29/2022 22:28:56; Total Duration:36015.4719 Ms; Request Timeout 20000 Ms; Http Client Timeout:180000 Ms; Activity id: 2f24681b-db18-44aa-afc8-e12ba02d8930;);

The reason I am looking to map the ports differently is i need to have two cosmos emulator docker containers running simultaneously.

Any assistance/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following method can help to solve the issue.

As we know that the ports will be the concatenation of the ports in all compose files, I would be a suggestable pattern by creating a new `docker-compose.dev.yml` file which contains all development port mappings, removing them from the base `docker-compose.yml` file.

`docker-compose.override.yml` will not be applied if you manually specify another override file (e.g. `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml`)