# Getting a 408 RequestTimeout on Cosmos Emulator (MacOS) - .NET Core 6.0

Tags: docker, macos, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to do a proof-of-concept of connecting to and working with a local Cosmos Emulator from a .NET project. I have my Cosmos Emulator running on a Docker container, and I can browse the Cosmos Explorer by navigating to `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html`. However, I am getting the following error below when connecting to the Cosmos instance from my .NET project:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: RequestTimeout (408); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 08b1bf4d-99a3-43dd-94d8-598354f7e4f7; Reason: (GatewayStoreClient Request Timeout. Start Time UTC:7/16/2022 4:53:39 PM; Total Duration:65269.468 Ms; Request Timeout 65000 Ms; Http Client Timeout:65000 Ms; Activity id: 08b1bf4d-99a3-43dd-94d8-598354f7e4f7;);
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosHttpClientCore.ExecuteHttpHelperAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, ResourceType resourceType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosHttpClientCore.SendHttpHelperAsync(Func`1 createRequestMessageAsync, ResourceType resourceType, HttpTimeoutPolicy timeoutPolicy, IClientSideRequestStatistics clientSideRequestStatistics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayStoreClient.InvokeAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, ResourceType resourceType, Uri physicalAddress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayStoreModel.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.ProcessMessageAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage, Func`2 createResponse)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateDatabaseResponse(Database database, ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.<>c__DisplayClass54_0.<<CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult](ITrace trace, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, String operationName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync[TResult](String operationName, RequestOptions requestOptions, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, TraceComponent traceComponent, TraceLevel traceLevel)
   at Program.InitializeDatabaseAndContainer(String accountEndpoint, String primaryKey, String databaseName) in /Users/matt/source/azure-cosmos-docker/TestCosmosDocker/TestCosmosDocker/Program.cs:line 109
   at Program.Main() in /Users/matt/source/azure-cosmos-docker/TestCosmosDocker/TestCosmosDocker/Program.cs:line 33
   at Program.<Main>()
--- Cosmos Diagnostics ---{"Summary":{"GatewayCalls":{"(0, 0)":1}},"name":"CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync","id":"545e7145-f0b7-4c7e-9993-c2ca9d3ece02","start time":"04:53:39:257","duration in milliseconds":65587.1384,"data":{"Client Configuration":{"Client Created Time Utc":"2022-07-16T16:53:39.1505710Z","MachineId":"hashedMachineName:4a41c3d5-a264-2df2-a0c9-fc104350c1bf","NumberOfClientsCreated":1,"NumberOfActiveClients":0,"ConnectionMode":"Gateway","User Agent":"cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.29.0|1|X64|Darwin 21.1.0 Darwin Kernel Ve|.NET 6.0.7|N|F 00000010|","ConnectionConfig":{"gw":"(cps:50, urto:10, p:False, httpf: True)","rntbd":"(cto: 5, icto: -1, mrpc: 30, mcpe: 65535, erd: True, pr: ReuseUnicastPort)","other":"(ed:False, be:False)"},"ConsistencyConfig":"(consistency: NotSet, prgns:[], apprgn: )","ProcessorCount":8}},"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler","id":"c0beb150-c3b0-42fe-8561-c6cee1fb7493","start time":"04:53:39:310","duration in milliseconds":65473.9117,"children":[{"name":"Waiting for Initialization of client to complete","id":"b8bb7584-4fee-4151-b3ef-666908d4e791","start time":"04:53:39:338","duration in milliseconds":384.8078},{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.DiagnosticsHandler","id":"6e8bcd35-24b4-4b05-bfbc-de4e99ee4e28","start time":"04:53:39:726","duration in milliseconds":65057.0317,"data":{"System Info":{"systemHistory":[{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:53:49.4578290Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.2742,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:53:59.4604740Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0554,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:54:09.4608060Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0083,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:54:19.4628340Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0293,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:54:29.4673550Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0221,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-16T16:54:39.7381800Z","cpu":"no info","memory":"no info","threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0109,"availableThreads":32766,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":0}]}},"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RetryHandler","id":"fc81cba1-9f08-4521-a1d3-0e37d3f077a2","start time":"04:53:39:727","duration in milliseconds":65055.62,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RouterHandler","id":"86614889-83f3-4c39-97bd-3e439e1fecc7","start time":"04:53:39:730","duration in milliseconds":65033.8201,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler","id":"4764abb2-6f15-475e-92f5-3c3421a0fe0c","start time":"04:53:39:731","duration in milliseconds":65032.3511,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayStoreModel Transport Request","id":"7012e432-2e2c-4636-8ab1-7e630af92c4b","start time":"04:53:39:743","duration in milliseconds":65013.3039,"data":{"Client Side Request Stats":{"Id":"AggregatedClientSideRequestStatistics","ContactedReplicas":[],"RegionsContacted":[],"FailedReplicas":[],"AddressResolutionStatistics":[],"StoreResponseStatistics":[],"HttpResponseStats":[{"StartTimeUTC":"2022-07-16T16:53:39.7506050Z","DurationInMs":65267.718,"RequestUri":"https://172.29.0.2:8081/dbs/test-database","ResourceType":"Database","HttpMethod":"GET","ActivityId":"08b1bf4d-99a3-43dd-94d8-598354f7e4f7","ExceptionType":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException","ExceptionMessage":"A task was canceled."}]}}}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

This is the code that is throwing the error:

```
// For local testing purposes, ignore SSL validation
CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
        {
            HttpClientFactory = () =>
            {
                HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                };

                return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
            },
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
        };

using var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==", cosmosClientOptions);

await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("test-database");
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  cosmos-db:
    container_name: cosmosdb
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator"
    tty: true
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 3G
    cpu_count: 2
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
    ports:
       - "8081:8081"
       - "10251:10251"
       - "10252:10252"
       - "10253:10253"
       - "10254:10254"
    volumes:
       - vol_cosmos:/data/db

volumes: 
  vol_cosmos:
```

I've run this exact code on another computer running Linux without any issues. I'm wondering if there's something on the MacOS side that is blocking this request?

Additionally, I'm running on an Intel Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem. I came across this SO page: [Cosmos SDK experiences timeouts if mapped ports in docker-compose file differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751494/cosmos-sdk-experiences-timeouts-if-mapped-ports-in-docker-compose-file-differ)

I got it working with the following code

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    cosmos:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
        container_name: cosmos
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
          - 10251:10251
          - 10252:10252
          - 10253:10253
          - 10254:10254
        expose:
          - "8081"
          - "10251-10255"
        environment:
          - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=6
          - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=false
          - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=127.0.0.1
```

Code that's working

```
var httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
};

CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    HttpClientFactory = () => new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler),
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
    RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)
};
                
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(
    "https://localhost:8081",
    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    cosmosClientOptions);

var dbResponse = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("test-database");
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I spent 2 days with the issue until I tried this docker-compose and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: For those this solution did not work, increasing the partition count might do the trick. Flag is "AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT" for those using docker. Or instead of gateway mode, use direct mode.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the partition count (will however use more resources and take longer to start) or setting the connection mode to Direct seems to improve things (I'm running Cosmos on my machine, not docker). If I run Cosmos in a container (docker) I still get these random timeouts though, even if I increase the request timeout (.WithRequestTimeout()).

Would be great if someone from Microsoft shed some light here. Ideally I would prefer to run Cosmos in docker.